# lower bound of norm

Tags: upper-lower-bounds

Is there any analytic form for a lower bound of $\|AB-BC\|_F$ ?
$C$ is a similarity transform of $A$, i.e., $C = P^{-1} A P$. 
 I know that
$\|AB\|_F$ is bounded by $\|A^{-1}\|_2^{-1} \|B\|_F$ and $\|A\|_F \|B\|_F$
and $\|BC\|_F$ is bounded by $\|C^{-1}\|_2^{-1} \|B\|_F$ and $\|C\|_F \|B\|_F$
Intuitively the lower bound for $\| AB - BC \|_F$ is linear to $\| B \|_F$, but I cannot prove it.

Comment: Use "\|" for norm and enclose mathematical expressions by $ ... $.

Comment: For example, \$\|x\|_2\$ for $\|x\|_2$.

Comment: Thanks. edited.